# PHP string convert to array

Tags: php, arrays, string

```
$paypal_details = "array (
  'last_name' => 'Savani',      
  'item_name' => 'Description and pricing details here.',
  'item_number' => '101',      
  'custom' => 'localhost',      
  'period' => '1',
  'amount' => '10.01'
)";
```

Here is sample string in which contain full array. 
Is this possible to convert string to array as it is?

Comment: Only `eval($paypal_details)`

Comment: While `eval()` would do what you ask for all this is a horrible idea. It opens potential security holes a mile wide. Question is: why do you have a situation like that? Can't you avoid this?

Comment: I would seriously advice against using `eval()` for anything other than debugging. Try using `explode()`

Comment: If i can avoid this, then i can already do it, but not possible. I get response form third party.

Comment: `$paypal_details = array (
  'last_name' => 'Savani',      
  'item_name' => 'Description and pricing details here.',
  'item_number' => '101',      
  'custom' => 'localhost',      
  'period' => '1',
  'amount' => '10.01'
);`

Comment: Hello Anant, please check array proper, not simple array, this is string inside array.

Comment: The array, that you want to turn from string to array, is it the product of print_r? because if it is, then you can write a function to reverse it, because then you have rules to follow.

Answer (score 1):

You really should try to get the information in JSON or XML format instead, which both can be parsed natively by PHP. If that is not possible you can use the code snippet below to get a PHP array from the string. It uses [regular expressions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_regular_expression.htm) to turn the string into JSON format and then parses it using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Improvements should of course be made to handle escaped single quotes within values etc., but it is a start.

```
$paypal_details = "array (
  'last_name' => 'Savani',
  'item_name' => 'Description and pricing details here.',
  'item_number' => '101',
  'custom' => 'localhost',
  'period' => '1',
  'amount' => '10.01'
)";

# Transform into JSON and parse into array
$array = json_decode(
    preg_replace(
        "/^\s*'(.*)' => '(.*)'/m", # Turn 'foo' => 'bar'
        '"$1": "$2"',              # into "foo": "bar"
        preg_replace(
            "/array \((.*)\)/s",   # Turn array (...)
            '{$1}',                # into { ... }
            $paypal_details
        )
    ),
    true
);

echo "Last name: " . $array["last_name"] . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
Last name: Savani
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `explode()` function.

```
<?php

$str = "Hello world. It's a beautiful day.";
print_r(explode(" ", $str));
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp

Comment: Please check I have complete array but in string format (" "). With explode function explode in two parts with delimiter. here is no fix word.

Comment: @user3146706 he has provided you with a solution, please check the answer before rejecting it.

Comment: @user3146706 user provide simple string to array. But here is the array inside the string need to make again array. condition are different.

Comment: @user3146706 so you basically want us to program the whole thing for you? that is not the purpose of SO.